# Compound Modifiers and Hyphens

Tags: punctuation

Would you say "case-study-rich presentation" or "case study-rich presentation"?

Comment: I wouldn't say either but then I hate business-speak with a passion.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to avoid either and say **a presentation, rich in case studies...**
If you must, case study-rich is more correct, as case study is generally not hyphenated.

Comment: There has been a discussion on ELU about compound pre-modifiers. Hyphenation rules are not set in stone, and it was felt that clarity rather than prescriptivism was more important. _Case study rich_ is a cohesive unit, like _grizzly bear like_ (meaning 'like a grizzly bear')  and hyphenation of the compound premodifier helps to disambiguate (or at least comprehend more quickly).

Comment: I agree; too many hyphens gets cluttery.  It may sound okay verbally, but reading it is kind of awful.