# Using hyphens: "Mona-Lisa-like" or "Mona Lisa-like"?

Tags: orthography

Would it be correct to say:

> The person had a Mona-Lisa-like expression.

or

> The person had a Mona Lisa-like expression.

It strikes me that the former is correct, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: According to this article's title apparently it is: Mona Lisa-like. http://www.nbcnews.com/id/31320879/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/nude-mona-lisa-like-painting-surfaces/#.VmZlNHsx5mo
WARNING pictures may be disturbing. Not writing an answer as I can't yet prove that the first example is wrong or right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/286121/142429

Comment: I'm really tempted to use quotation marks to say "Mona Lisa"-like just so that _Mona Lisa_ is treated as a single entity.

Comment: I believe that _The Chicago Manual of Style_ recommends using a space and an en dash: _Mona Lisa–like_.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be correct to say:

*The person had a Mona-Lisa-like expression.*

or

*The person had a Mona Lisa-like expression.*

Neither of them is very good English at all - ***Mona Lisa like*** sounds forced and artificial - and I would be looking for an alternative sentence construction.